# 50% chance to make a boolean true or not by clicking a button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've been stuck on this for a while, I'm trying to figure out how to make a boolean have a 50% chance to be set to true after clicking a button and a 50% chance to keep it false.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you really want? any code sample please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
bool yourBool= false;
Random rand = new Random();

if (rand.Next(0, 2) != 0)
{
    yourBool = true;
}
```

Comment: Told me to wait 3 minutes. But yeah thanks. I'm not sure why I was downvoted though :/

Comment: @Revan114, Maybe some people not clear enough about what you are asking. that may be the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply generate a random integer that can take values 0 or 1:

```
Random rand = new Random();
bool variable = rand.Next(2) == 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just generate an Integer from Random.Next and look if it's 0 or 1.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool b = new Random().Next(2) == 0; // Will return false or true
}
```